# how to use "had lived" correctly

Tags: past-perfect

Okay, I'm not sure how to phrase this question, but I want to know if below sentences are correct.

> Because I met him in New York in 2011 and he moved here last year, I can assume that he at least **had lived** in New York from 2011 to 2012 (before he moved here).

In this sentence, should I say "had lived" and omit the "before he moved here" part?

or

> Prior to his move, I know he **had lived** in A from 2011 to 2012.

Or should I just change everything to simple past?

> I first met him in New York in 2011 and we became friends. I don't know where he lived before living in New York, but I know the fact that he **lived** in New York prior to his move to here, which **took** place in 2012.

This sentence sounds so wordy, so I was wondering if I can just use "had lived" to stress m point that I can assume that he lived in New York before moving "here". I heard a friend use "had lived" but couldn't quite figure out the correct usage.

Comment: If you want to use the simple past, change the sentence to this: _I know that he lived in A before he moved to B last year_. Eliminate all that verbosity. Words that do no work provide the brain with cerebral lard & permanently damage the fingertips.

Comment: You can also omit _year_ in "from year 2011 to 2012": There isn't any possibility of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The responses in the comments seem to me sufficient to constitute an answer, so I'm posting this to clear the record:

> If you want to use the simple past, change the sentence to this: I know that he lived in A before he moved to B last year. Eliminate all that verbosity. Words that do no work provide the brain with cerebral lard & permanently damage the fingertips. – *A since-departed (and lamented) user, Bill Franke*
>
> You can also omit *year* in "from year 2011 to 2012": There isn't any possibility of confusion. – *kiamlaluno*